# How to document with Swagger @RequestParam Map<String, String>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to document my RESTFUL API made with Spring Boot using Swagger UI, the problem is that when i open the swagger-ui.html to view my documentation.

When I open the controller on the swagger-ui.html to view my methods, they are blank, with only one parameter which is a Map type. Obvious with this map object I fetch the parameters I need and make the request to the database or whatever.

I would like to know how I could tell swagger that those methods need some specific values or arguments, not just a simple Map object , i would like to tell the user with the api doc that he needs to input the key1,key2,key3 to call this method.

There is an example of one method

```
@GetMapping("/technical/sma/**")
    public ArrayList<RegistroTecnico> recuperarSMA(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParameters) {
        return this.recuperarIndicadorAVG("sma",queryParameters);
    }
```

I would like to tell swagger to document the parameters needed for the method manually if there is no way.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is no direct support from SpringFox in Spring boot application for Map type. You have to write your own custom plugin. You can get more details from this issue.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1503#

Comment: is there any tutorial of how to do it?

Comment: There is no concrete example but this link https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2671 will give you some insight.

Answer (score 1):

I think till now there is no support for Map type parameter auto-detect doc from swagger.
If you need auto-detect Param from swagger just convert the map into POJO and wrap it in response body but for that you need to change request type to POST.